# How to set LayoutManager in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I want show some `RecyclerViews`.
I want **show 3 item in one row**, I my application should use **4** `recyclerView` because each `recyclerVews` each data other **API**.

In one of `RecyclerView` I can show 3 Item in one row, and I should show another 3 `recyclerViews` above of this `RecyclerView`.

I want show such as this image : [enter link description here](https://image.ibb.co/duO5ga/Screenshot_15021826132.jpg)

but show me such as below image : [enter link description here](https://image.ibb.co/cppp7F/Screenshot_1502182613.jpg)

**I write below code in Java :**

```
if (movieResponse.getData().getStars().size() > 0) {
                            starsModel.clear();
                            starsModel.addAll(movieResponse.getData().getStars());
                            castAdapter = new CastAdapter(context, starsModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setAdapter(castAdapter);
                        } else {
                            goneView(infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Directors
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getDirectors().size() > 0) {
                            directorsModel.clear();
                            directorsModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getDirectors().get(0));
                            directorAdapter = new DirectorAdapter(context, directorsModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setAdapter(directorAdapter);
                        } else {
                            goneView(infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Writers
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getWriters().size() > 0) {
                            writersModel.clear();
                            writersModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getWriters().get(0));
                            writerAdapter = new WriterAdapter(context, writersModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setAdapter(writerAdapter);
                        } else {
                            invisibleView(infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Writers2
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getWriters().size() > 0) {
                            writersModel.clear();
                            writersModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getWriters().get(0));
                            writerAdapter = new WriterAdapter(context, writersModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setAdapter(writerAdapter);
                        }
```

**My XML code:**

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5" />
```

How to show 3 up `recyclerview's` items **align** by under `recyclerView`?

Answer (score 1):

> this means 3 columns

```html
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
```

> and set item's width to match parent that is custom layout you inflate via adapter